# Punto Switcher не работает в NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, windows-10, java

Windows 10 Pro x64
Punto Switcher 4.3.6
NetBeans 8.2 (Java: 1.8.0_162; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.162-b12)

пытаюсь переключить раскладку набранного текста в NetBeans, нажимаю F12 (в настройках NetBeans этот хот-кей не используется), Punto Switcher отрабатывает конвертацию - и получаю абракадабру вместо переключению набранного текста (слова)

какие могут быть варианты решения проблемы?

Comment: не использовать Punto Switcher? Если память не изменяет NetBeans этим грешит

Comment: Punto Switcher - очень удобная вещь, не только практически безглючным переключением набранного (использую 3 языка ввода), но и менеджером буфера обмена. альтернатив пока что не вижу, увы.